# AsyncTask and changes of orientation

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog, screen-orientation

I've problem with the re-creation of the activity, the progress dialog and the Async Task when change the orientation of the screen. I saw some solutions here and i decided to use the onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance() to save the instance of AsyncTask. Well, in onCreate i check if there is an instance of AsyncTask and, if exist, i show a new Progress Dialog. But this dialog blocks the UI in an infinite loop (in the onPostExecute there is dialog.dismiss() ) and the activity doesn't show the results of course.

**onCreate**

```java
getDirection = (GetDirection) getLastCustomNonConfigurationInstance();
if(getDirection != null) {
  dialog = new ProgressDialog(RouteActivity.this);
  dialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.loading_data));
  dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
  dialog.setCancelable(false);
  dialog.show();
} else {
  getDirection = new GetDirection();
  getDirection.execute();
}
```

**onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance**

```java
@Override
public Object onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance() {
  return getDirection;
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
  if (dialog.isShowing()) {
    dialog.dismiss();
  }
}
```

**EDIT #1**:
I adopted the solution of Kingfisher with Fragment and Retained Fragment but there is a NPE on Expandable Listview when i change the orientation during the doInBackground of AsyncTask.

```java
08-14 12:50:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(22739): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-14 12:50:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(22739): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-14 12:50:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(22739):    at com.pasquini.adapter.ListRouteExpandableAdapter.getGroupCount(ListRouteExpandableAdapter.java:78)
08-14 12:50:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(22739):    at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getCount(ExpandableListConnector.java:399)
08-14 12:50:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(22739):    at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:460)
08-14 12:50:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(22739):    at android.widget.ExpandableListView.setAdapter(ExpandableListView.java:470)
08-14 12:50:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(22739):    at com.pasquini.activity.RouteActivity.onPostExecute(RouteActivity.java:792)
08-14 12:50:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(22739):    at com.pasquini.fragment.GetDirectionFragment$GetDirectionTask.onPostExecute(GetDirectionFragment.java:244)
08-14 12:50:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(22739):    at com.pasquini.fragment.GetDirectionFragment$GetDirectionTask.onPostExecute(GetDirectionFragment.java:1)
08-14 12:50:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(22739):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
08-14 12:50:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(22739):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
08-14 12:50:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(22739):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
08-14 12:50:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(22739):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-14 12:50:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(22739):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-14 12:50:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(22739):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
08-14 12:50:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(22739):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 12:50:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(22739):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-14 12:50:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(22739):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
08-14 12:50:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(22739):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
08-14 12:50:40.866: E/AndroidRuntime(22739):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method).
```

**Here the code in Fragment:**

```java
public class GetDirectionFragment extends Fragment {

private Map<Leg, List<Step>> legsCollection;
private ArrayList<Object> legsAndSteps;
private List<Leg> legs;
private List<Poi> pois;
private List<LatLng> polyz;

/**
   * Callback interface through which the fragment will report the
   * task's progress and results back to the Activity.
   */
  public static interface TaskCallbacks {
    void onPreExecute();
    void onPostExecute();
    List<Poi> getListPoiByRoute();
    void setLegs(List<Leg> legs, Map<Leg, List<Step>> legsCollection);
    void setPolyline(List<LatLng> polyz);

  }

  private TaskCallbacks callbacks;
  private GetDirectionTask getDirectionTask;

  /**
   * Hold a reference to the parent Activity so we can report the
   * task's current progress and results. The Android framework 
   * will pass us a reference to the newly created Activity after 
   * each configuration change.
   */
  @Override
  public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        callbacks = (TaskCallbacks) activity;
    } catch(ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement TaskCallbacks");
    }
    pois = callbacks.getListPoiByRoute();
  }

  /**
   * This method will only be called once when the retained
   * Fragment is first created.
   */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Retain this fragment across configuration changes.
    setRetainInstance(true);

    // Create and execute the background task.
    getDirectionTask = new GetDirectionTask();
    getDirectionTask.execute();
  }

  /**
   * Set the callback to null so we don't accidentally leak the 
   * Activity instance.
   */
  @Override
  public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    callbacks = null;
  }

  private class GetDirectionTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
          if (callbacks != null) {
              callbacks.onPreExecute();
          }
        }

        /**
         * Note that we do NOT call the callback object's methods
         * directly from the background thread, as this could result 
         * in a race condition.
         */
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... ignore) {
                List<String> lats = new ArrayList<String>();
                List<String> longs = new ArrayList<String>();

                for(Poi poi: pois) {
                    lats.add(poi.getCoordinates().getLatitude());
                    longs.add(poi.getCoordinates().getLongitude());
                }

                String stringUrl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" +
                        "json?";
                //if(actualLanguage.equals("en")) {
                //  stringUrl += "language=en_EN";
                //} else {
                    stringUrl += "language=it";
                //}
                stringUrl+="&mode=walking&units=metric&origin=" +
                         lats.get(0) + "," +
                         longs.get(0);

                stringUrl += "&destination=" +
                        lats.get(pois.size()-1) + "," +
                        longs.get(pois.size()-1) + "&" +
                        "waypoints=";


                for(int i = 1; i<=lats.size()-2 && i<=longs.size()-2; i++) {
                    stringUrl += lats.get(i)+","+longs.get(i);
                    if(i==(lats.size()-2) && i==(longs.size()-2)) {
                        stringUrl += "&sensor=false";
                    } else {
                        stringUrl +="|";
                    }
                }

                Log.i("urlgoogle", stringUrl);

                StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(stringUrl);
                    HttpURLConnection httpconn = (HttpURLConnection) url
                            .openConnection();
                    if (httpconn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(httpconn.getInputStream()),
                                8192);
                        String strLine = null;

                        while ((strLine = input.readLine()) != null) {
                            response.append(strLine);
                        }
                        input.close();
                    }

                    String jsonOutput = response.toString();

                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonOutput);


                    // routesArray contains ALL routes
                    JSONArray routesArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");
                    // Grab the first route
                    JSONObject route = routesArray.getJSONObject(0);

                    JSONArray legsArray = route.getJSONArray("legs");
                    legs = new ArrayList<Leg>();
                    legsAndSteps = new ArrayList<Object>();
                    String htmlInstructions;

                    legsCollection = new LinkedHashMap<Leg, List<Step>>();

                    for(int i=0; i<legsArray.length(); i++) {
                        List<Step> steps = new ArrayList<Step>();
                        Leg leg = new Leg();
                        //int idLeg = 0;
                        JSONObject legJson = legsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        leg.setDistance(legJson.getJSONObject("distance").getString("text"));
                        leg.setDuration(legJson.getJSONObject("duration").getString("text"));
                        leg.setEndAddress(legJson.getString("end_address"));
                        leg.setStartAddress(legJson.getString("start_address"));
                        leg.setIdLeg(pois.get(i).getId());
                        leg.setStartPoiName(pois.get(i).getName());
                        leg.setEndPoiName(pois.get(i+1).getName());

                        legsAndSteps.add(leg);

                        JSONArray stepsArray = legJson.getJSONArray("steps");
                        for(int j=0; j<stepsArray.length(); j++) {
                            Step step = new Step();
                            JSONObject stepJson = stepsArray.getJSONObject(j);
                            step.setDistance(stepJson.getJSONObject("distance").getString("text"));
                            step.setDuration(stepJson.getJSONObject("duration").getString("text"));
                            htmlInstructions = android.text.Html.fromHtml(stepJson.getString("html_instructions")).toString();
                            step.setInstructions(htmlInstructions);
                            //step.setIdLeg(idLeg);

                            //Aggiunto per Exp
                            steps.add(step);

                            legsAndSteps.add(step);

                        }
                        legsCollection.put(leg, steps);


                        legs.add(leg);
                    }



                    JSONObject poly = route.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
                    String polyline = poly.getString("points");
                    polyz = decodePoly(polyline);

                    callbacks.setLegs(legs, legsCollection);
                    callbacks.setPolyline(polyz);

                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

          return null;
        }



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void ignore) {
          if (callbacks != null) {
              callbacks.onPostExecute();
          }
        }
      }

  /* Method to decode polyline points */
    private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

        [code...]
    }
```

}

**Here the code in Activity**:

```java
 @Override
public void onPostExecute() {


     expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_routepoi);
     ListRouteExpandableAdapter expListAdapter = new ListRouteExpandableAdapter(
             getApplicationContext(), legs, legsCollection);
     expListView.setAdapter(expListAdapter);

     setGroupIndicatorToRight();
     expListView.setChildDivider(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.divider_route));

    [code...]

    dialog.dismiss();


}

@Override
public void setLegs(List<Leg> legs, Map<Leg, List<Step>> legsCollection) {
    this.legs = legs;
    this.legsCollection = legsCollection;


}

@Override
public void setPolyline(List<LatLng> polyz) {
    this.polyz = polyz;

}
```

**EDIT #2**: I tried the new solution of Kingfisher but there is always an NPE in doInBackground method. If i don't change the orientation of screen during the loading, app doesn't crash and show data on listview.

```java
08-14 17:27:44.897: I/AsyncTask(30604): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-14 17:27:44.897: E/AndroidRuntime(30604): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-14 17:27:44.897: E/AndroidRuntime(30604): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-14 17:27:44.897: E/AndroidRuntime(30604):    at com.pasquini.activity.RouteActivity.onPostExecute(RouteActivity.java:847)
08-14 17:27:44.897: E/AndroidRuntime(30604):    at com.pasquini.fragment.GetDirectionFragment$GetDirectionTask.onPostExecute(GetDirectionFragment.java:253)
08-14 17:27:44.897: E/AndroidRuntime(30604):    at com.pasquini.fragment.GetDirectionFragment$GetDirectionTask.onPostExecute(GetDirectionFragment.java:1)
08-14 17:27:44.897: E/AndroidRuntime(30604):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
08-14 17:27:44.897: E/AndroidRuntime(30604):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
08-14 17:27:44.897: E/AndroidRuntime(30604):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
08-14 17:27:44.897: E/AndroidRuntime(30604):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-14 17:27:44.897: E/AndroidRuntime(30604):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-14 17:27:44.897: E/AndroidRuntime(30604):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
08-14 17:27:44.897: E/AndroidRuntime(30604):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 17:27:44.897: E/AndroidRuntime(30604):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-14 17:27:44.897: E/AndroidRuntime(30604):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
08-14 17:27:44.897: E/AndroidRuntime(30604):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
08-14 17:27:44.897: E/AndroidRuntime(30604):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Here the code in Fragment:**

```java
public class GetDirectionFragment extends Fragment {

private Map<Leg, List<Step>> legsCollection;
private ArrayList<Object> legsAndSteps;
private List<Leg> legs;
private List<Poi> pois;
private List<LatLng> polyz;

/**
   * Callback interface through which the fragment will report the
   * task's progress and results back to the Activity.
   */
  public static interface TaskCallbacks {
    void onPreExecute();
    void onPostExecute();
    List<Poi> getListPoiByRoute();
    void setLegs(List<Leg> legs, Map<Leg, List<Step>> legsCollection);
    void setPolyline(List<LatLng> polyz);

  }

  private TaskCallbacks callbacks;
  private GetDirectionTask getDirectionTask;

  /**
   * Hold a reference to the parent Activity so we can report the
   * task's current progress and results. The Android framework 
   * will pass us a reference to the newly created Activity after 
   * each configuration change.
   */
  @Override
  public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        callbacks = (TaskCallbacks) activity;
    } catch(ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement TaskCallbacks");
    }
    pois = callbacks.getListPoiByRoute();
  }

  /**
   * This method will only be called once when the retained
   * Fragment is first created.
   */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Retain this fragment across configuration changes.
    setRetainInstance(true);

    // Create and execute the background task.
    getDirectionTask = new GetDirectionTask();
    getDirectionTask.execute();
  }

  /**
   * Set the callback to null so we don't accidentally leak the 
   * Activity instance.
   */
  @Override
  public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    callbacks = null;
  }

  private class GetDirectionTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
          if (callbacks != null) {
              callbacks.onPreExecute();
          }
        }

        /**
         * Note that we do NOT call the callback object's methods
         * directly from the background thread, as this could result 
         * in a race condition.
         */
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... ignore) {
                List<String> lats = new ArrayList<String>();
                List<String> longs = new ArrayList<String>();

                for(Poi poi: pois) {
                    lats.add(poi.getCoordinates().getLatitude());
                    longs.add(poi.getCoordinates().getLongitude());
                }

                String stringUrl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" +
                        "json?";
                //if(actualLanguage.equals("en")) {
                //  stringUrl += "language=en_EN";
                //} else {
                    stringUrl += "language=it";
                //}
                stringUrl+="&mode=walking&units=metric&origin=" +
                         lats.get(0) + "," +
                         longs.get(0);

                stringUrl += "&destination=" +
                        lats.get(pois.size()-1) + "," +
                        longs.get(pois.size()-1) + "&" +
                        "waypoints=";


                for(int i = 1; i<=lats.size()-2 && i<=longs.size()-2; i++) {
                    stringUrl += lats.get(i)+","+longs.get(i);
                    if(i==(lats.size()-2) && i==(longs.size()-2)) {
                        stringUrl += "&sensor=false";
                    } else {
                        stringUrl +="|";
                    }
                }

                Log.i("urlgoogle", stringUrl);

                StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(stringUrl);
                    HttpURLConnection httpconn = (HttpURLConnection) url
                            .openConnection();
                    if (httpconn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(httpconn.getInputStream()),
                                8192);
                        String strLine = null;

                        while ((strLine = input.readLine()) != null) {
                            response.append(strLine);
                        }
                        input.close();
                    }

                    String jsonOutput = response.toString();

                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonOutput);


                    // routesArray contains ALL routes
                    JSONArray routesArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");
                    // Grab the first route
                    JSONObject route = routesArray.getJSONObject(0);

                    JSONArray legsArray = route.getJSONArray("legs");
                    legs = new ArrayList<Leg>();
                    legsAndSteps = new ArrayList<Object>();
                    String htmlInstructions;

                    legsCollection = new LinkedHashMap<Leg, List<Step>>();

                    for(int i=0; i<legsArray.length(); i++) {
                        List<Step> steps = new ArrayList<Step>();
                        Leg leg = new Leg();
                        //int idLeg = 0;
                        JSONObject legJson = legsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        leg.setDistance(legJson.getJSONObject("distance").getString("text"));
                        leg.setDuration(legJson.getJSONObject("duration").getString("text"));
                        leg.setEndAddress(legJson.getString("end_address"));
                        leg.setStartAddress(legJson.getString("start_address"));
                        leg.setIdLeg(pois.get(i).getId());
                        leg.setStartPoiName(pois.get(i).getName());
                        leg.setEndPoiName(pois.get(i+1).getName());

                        legsAndSteps.add(leg);

                        JSONArray stepsArray = legJson.getJSONArray("steps");
                        for(int j=0; j<stepsArray.length(); j++) {
                            Step step = new Step();
                            JSONObject stepJson = stepsArray.getJSONObject(j);
                            step.setDistance(stepJson.getJSONObject("distance").getString("text"));
                            step.setDuration(stepJson.getJSONObject("duration").getString("text"));
                            htmlInstructions = android.text.Html.fromHtml(stepJson.getString("html_instructions")).toString();
                            step.setInstructions(htmlInstructions);
                            //step.setIdLeg(idLeg);

                            steps.add(step);

                            legsAndSteps.add(step);

                        }
                        legsCollection.put(leg, steps);


                        legs.add(leg);
                    }



                    JSONObject poly = route.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
                    String polyline = poly.getString("points");
                    polyz = decodePoly(polyline);

                    setLegs(legs, legsCollection);
                    setPolyline(polyz);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.i(TAG, e.toString());
                }

          return null;
        }



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void ignore) {
          if (callbacks != null) {
              callbacks.onPostExecute();
          }
        }
      }

  /* Method to decode polyline points */
    private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

        [code...]
    }

public void setLegs(List<Leg> legs, Map<Leg, List<Step>> legsCollection) {
            this.legs = legs;
            this.legsCollection = legsCollection;
        }

    public void setPolyline(List<LatLng> polyz) {
        this.polyz = polyz;

    }

    public List<Leg> getLegs() {
        return this.legs;
    }

    public Map<Leg, List<Step>> getMap() {
        return this.legsCollection;
    }

    public List<LatLng> getPolyline() {
        return this.polyz;
    }
```

}

**Here the code in Activity**:

```java
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               [code...]
           FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
           getDirectionFragment = (GetDirectionFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(TASK_FRAGMENT_TAG);

            // If the Fragment is non-null, then it is currently being
            // retained across a configuration change.
            if (getDirectionFragment == null) {
                getDirectionFragment = new GetDirectionFragment();
                fm.beginTransaction().add(getDirectionFragment, TASK_FRAGMENT_TAG).commit();

         [code...]
            }

 @Override
public void onPostExecute() {

           legs = getDirectionFragment.getLegs();
    legsCollection = getDirectionFragment.getMap();
    polyz = getDirectionFragment.getPolyline();

     expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_routepoi);
     ListRouteExpandableAdapter expListAdapter = new ListRouteExpandableAdapter(
             getApplicationContext(), legs, legsCollection);
     expListView.setAdapter(expListAdapter);

     setGroupIndicatorToRight();
     expListView.setChildDivider(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.divider_route));

    [code...]



}
```

Comment: Blocking the UI is due to not updating the AsyncTask's reference to the dialog to the NEW dialog created after the orientation change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this link: [Handling Configuration Changes with Fragments](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html) or you can use [AsyncTaskLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html). I recommend to use `Retained Fragment` to handle configuration changes. Read article carefully.
**Edited:** dont call `callback.set` function in `doInBackground`.You should find your `Retained Fragment` when activity re-created, and in `onPost function` try to use `Retained Fragment`'s get function to get the list result.

```
//Activity recreated
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
mTaskFragment = (TaskFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("task");

//onPost method
yourList = mTaskFragment.getLegsAndMoveList();
// Do lisview data changing here
```

Hope this help.

Comment: +1 on the AsyncTaskLoader, i think it's the best option for dealing with Asynchronous Tasks without problems with Activities.

Comment: Well, i tried your edit but there is always an NPE in the doInBackground method (try-catch block). Boh, very singular

Comment: @Daniele You should post your edited code and your error logcat as well. The error may not as what you think.

Comment: @Daniele you should debug to get position where NPE comes from!

Comment: @Kingfisher Perfect, i found the NPE problem and your solution works fine

Answer (score 0):

use `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` in tag activity in manifest file .this cause activity dont run with changing orientation again and you dont need save any data

Answer (score 0):

You never update the dialog in your async task so that it will dismiss the new one(hence the seemingly infinite loop, but really just blocking the UI, no loop).

When you save your state and reload, you need to update that dialog to the new one so that dismiss() will dismiss the right one.

Just add a setDialog() method to your task and in onCreate() call it with the new dialog.

One more thing, you might want to consider adding a check to see if the AsyncTask finished before you set the new dialog to it and display it. There is a chance it could have finished after your orientation change but before onCreate(), in which case you would have a blocked UI.  This is safe to do in onCreate since onPostExecute  and onCreate both run on the same thread(UI thread).

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a relative simple solution for this problem. You can use an Holder which has a reference to your running AsyncTask.

**The Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.container, new MainFragment());
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

**The Fragment:**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, SampleAsyncTask.Callback {


    private Button mExecuteButton;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        mExecuteButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.execute_button);
        mExecuteButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        SampleAsyncTask asyncTask = SampleAsyncTask.Holder.Instance.get();
        asyncTask.setCallback(this);

        if (asyncTask.isRunning()) {
            showProgressDialog(asyncTask.getProgress());
        }

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDetach () {

        SampleAsyncTask asyncTask = SampleAsyncTask.Holder.Instance.get();
        if (asyncTask.isRunning()) {
            asyncTask.setCallback(null);
        }

        if (mProgressDialog != null) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            mProgressDialog = null;
        }

        super.onDetach();
    }


    private void showProgressDialog (int progress) {

        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mProgressDialog.setButton(ProgressDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", makeNegativeButtonListener());
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress);
        mProgressDialog.setMax(100);

        mProgressDialog.show();
    }


    private DialogInterface.OnClickListener makeNegativeButtonListener () {

        DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                SampleAsyncTask asyncTask = SampleAsyncTask.Holder.Instance.get();
                if (asyncTask.isRunning()) {
                    asyncTask.cancel(true);
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        };

        return listener;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick (View v) {

        SampleAsyncTask asyncTask = SampleAsyncTask.Holder.Instance.get();
        asyncTask.setCallback(this);

        if (!asyncTask.isRunning()) {
            showProgressDialog(0);
            asyncTask.execute(100, 200);
        }
    }


    // SampleAsyncTask.Callback implementation


    @Override
    public void onPostExecute (boolean success) {

        String message = (success) ? "SUCCESS" : "FAIL";
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }


    @Override
    public void onProgressUpdate (int progressValue) {

        if (mProgressDialog != null) {
            mProgressDialog.setProgress(progressValue);
        }
    }
}
```

**The AsyncTask:**

```
public class SampleAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Boolean> {


    public static final String LOG_TAG = SampleAsyncTask.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final Callback LOG_CALLBACK = new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute (boolean success) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "#onPostExecute (" + success + ")");
        }


        @Override
        public void onProgressUpdate (int progressValue) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "#onProgressUpdate(" + progressValue + ")");
        }
    };

    private boolean mRunning = false;
    private int mProgress = -1;
    private Callback mCallback = LOG_CALLBACK;


    public void setCallback (Callback callback) {

        if (callback == null) {
            mCallback = LOG_CALLBACK;
        }
        else {
            mCallback = callback;
        }
    }


    public boolean isRunning () {

        return mRunning;
    }


    public int getProgress () {

        return mProgress;
    }


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground (Integer... params) {

        mRunning = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < params[0]; i++) {

            if (isCancelled()) {
                return false;
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(params[1]);
                mProgress = i;
                publishProgress(i);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute (Boolean success) {

        mRunning = false;
        Holder.Instance.reset();

        mCallback.onPostExecute(success);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate (Integer... values) {

        mCallback.onProgressUpdate(values[0]);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCancelled (Boolean aBoolean) {

        mRunning = false;
        Holder.Instance.reset();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCancelled () {

        mRunning = false;
        Holder.Instance.reset();
    }


    public enum Holder {

        Instance;
        private SampleAsyncTask mSampleAsyncTask;


        public SampleAsyncTask get () {

            if (mSampleAsyncTask == null) {
                mSampleAsyncTask = new SampleAsyncTask();
            }

            return mSampleAsyncTask;
        }


        private void reset () {

            mSampleAsyncTask = null;
        }
    }

    public interface Callback {

        public void onPostExecute (boolean success);
        public void onProgressUpdate (int progressValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I write samepl code to solve this problem

First step is make Application class:

```
public class TheApp extends Application {

private static TheApp sTheApp;
private HashMap<String, AsyncTask<?,?,?>> tasks = new HashMap<String, AsyncTask<?,?,?>>();

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    sTheApp = this;
}

public static TheApp get() {
    return sTheApp;
}

public void registerTask(String tag, AsyncTask<?,?,?> task) {
    tasks.put(tag, task);
}

public void unregisterTask(String tag) {
    tasks.remove(tag);
}

public AsyncTask<?,?,?> getTask(String tag) {
    return tasks.get(tag);
}
}
```

In AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name="com.example.tasktest.TheApp">
```

Code in activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Task1 mTask1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTask1 = (Task1)TheApp.get().getTask("task1");

}

/*
 * start task is not running jet
 */
public void handletask1(View v) {
    if (mTask1 == null) {
        mTask1 = new Task1();
        TheApp.get().registerTask("task1", mTask1);
        mTask1.execute();
    } else
        Toast.makeText(this, "Task is running...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

/*
 * cancel task if is not finished
 */
public void handelCancel(View v) {
    if (mTask1 != null)
        mTask1.cancel(false);
}

public class Task1 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            for(int i=0; i<120; i++) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                Log.i("tests", "loop=" + i);
                if (this.isCancelled()) {
                    Log.e("tests", "tssk cancelled");
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled(Void result) {
        TheApp.get().unregisterTask("task1");
        mTask1 = null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        TheApp.get().unregisterTask("task1");
        mTask1 = null;
    }
}

}
```

When activity orientation changes variable mTask is inited from app context. When task is finished variable is set to null and remove from memory.

For me its enough.